# ScrollView contains some TextView, but some textView's text can't been shown

Tags: android, uiscrollview

[image]

I put some textViews(or Button) in this AbsoluteLayout, and the AbsoluteLayout is in the ScrollView.

When I scroll the ScrollView, the textViews' text is not shown, but the textView above the screen can be shown correctly. Forget my poor English.
Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disable hardware acceleration for textView at runtime with the following code:

```
textView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

it works for me.